# purrr::map_dbl(...) Error - How to fix it?

Tags: r, purrr

Please note that I do not know how to code. I am using the code that someone wrote for some analysis that I need to run. I encountered a bunch of error messages that I was able to fix by installing the right packages such as purr.

However, when I reach the last line of the code, I get this error message:

```
Error in `map_dbl()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! Result must be length 1, not 0.
```

[image]

When I run rlang: I get this:

[image]

```
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─purrr::map_dbl(...)
 2. │ └─purrr:::map_("double", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
 3. │   └─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
 4. │     └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 5. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 6.   └─purrr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
 7.     └─cli::cli_abort(c(i = "In index: {i}."), parent = cnd, call = error_call)
 8.       └─rlang::abort(...)
```

Could anyone please explain what this means and, more importantly, what lines I should be entering to fix it?

Please feel free to let me know if additional details can help to figure this error out.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It means that no value was returned when it expected one returned. Likely the first element of `video_names` is not present in `scale_factors`.

Comment: I verified and this is not the case

Comment: Than it's hard to help further without further information and making your error reproducible. It would be easier to help if you could copy/paste the code and an example of your data using `dput()`.