# purrr::map_dbl(...) Error plotting ETS model forecast using Michael Foley's Time Series Analysis Tutorial

Tags: time-series, purrr

**To replicate the error**
Load libraries from https://bookdown.org/mpfoley1973/time-series/
Run code from https://bookdown.org/mpfoley1973/time-series/exponential.html section 4.1

Error in mutate from purrr
Error in `map_dbl()`:
In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! Result must be length 1, not 0.`

Still an R beginner so not sure how to debug the problem.
A search found this post [purrr::map_dbl(...) Error - How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73922731/purrrmap-dbl-error-how-to-fix-it) but this post had insufficient detail.

Code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(patchwork) #  arranging plots
library(glue)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts) # feature extraction and statistics
library(fable) # forecasting
library(tsibbledata)

 tsibbledata::global_economy %>%
   filter(Country == "Algeria") %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Exports)) +
   geom_line() +
   theme_light() +
   labs(title = "Algerian exports (% of GDP) show no trend or seasonality.")
 
 mdl_ses <- tsibbledata::global_economy %>%
   filter(Country == "Algeria") %>%
   model(ETS(Exports ~ error("A") + trend("N") + season("N")))
 
 mdl_ses %>% report()
 
 gg_tsresiduals(mdl_ses)
 
 mdl_ses_fc <- mdl_ses %>%
   forecast(h = 5) %>%
   mutate(sigma = map_dbl(Exports, ~pluck(.x, "sigma")),
          ci_025 = qnorm(.025, .mean, sigma),
          ci_975 = qnorm(.975, .mean, sigma))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### map() is crashing because pluck() is returning NULL

`pluck()` is looking for `"sigma"` in every index of the `Exports` column.

In an least some (possibly all) instances, `pluck()` finds nothing called `"sigma"` and so returns `NULL`. `map_dbl()` crashes when a `NULL` is returned, becuase `NULL` has length 0 and `map_dbl()` does not like things with length zero.

You work around this by using `map()` instead of `map_dbl()`; this will return `sigma` as a list-column which will include some `NULL` values. Examining this list-column (and the values of `Exports` at those rows) will give you a better idea of why `"sigma"` is missing from `Exports`.

Here's a minimal example to explain the nature of the error:

```r
library(purrr)

test <- list(
  list(foo = 1, bar = 2),
  list(foo = 3, bar = 4),
  list(foo = 5)           # 'bar' is missing here
)

## Plucking "foo" from the third element of `test`
## works just fine
pluck(test, 3, "foo")
#> [1] 5

## Plucking "bar" **also** works fine, but it returns 
## NULL (this is expected behaviour)
pluck(test, 3, "bar")
#> NULL

## When we look for 'foo', map_dbl() get's three numbers
## and combines them into a numerical vector

map_dbl(test, ~pluck(.x, "foo"))
#> [1] 1 3 5

## When we look for 'bar', map_dbl() gets two numbers and one
## instance of NULL. map_dbl() crashes, because that's how it
## responds to zero-length outputs.

map_dbl(test, ~pluck(.x, "bar"))
#> Error in `map_dbl()`:
#> ℹ In index: 3.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! Result must be length 1, not 0.
#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. ├─purrr::map_dbl(test, ~pluck(.x, "bar"))
#>  2. │ └─purrr:::map_("double", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
#>  3. │   ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
#>  4. │   │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  5. │   └─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
#>  6. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
#>  7.   └─purrr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  8.     └─cli::cli_abort(...)
#>  9.       └─rlang::abort(...)

## Using map() instead of map_dbl() circumvents the
## error, since map() can just package the NULL
## up into a list-element:

output <- map(test, ~pluck(.x, "bar"))
output
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This error is by-design: The `map_*` family of functions always return an output with the same length as their input. A list of length 3 can include a `NULL` value, but the numerical vector `c(2, 3, NULL)` is equivalent to `c(2, 3)` and has length 2. Accepting a `NULL` output could hence lead to unexpected behaviour from `map_dbl()`, which is why the function crashes.

---

PS: it could also be that `Exports$sigma` is not `NULL` but still has a length of zero (eg. `Exports <- list(foo = 10, sigma = numeric(0))`). In either case, the solution is the same.

Comment: Thanks Captain Hat for taking the time to explain the error so clearly with a worked example. Really appreciated and it helped me not only to understand this particular error but should help me when I debug future problems. Apologies for my late response but I have been off work.